# XML compare using xquery

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery

I'm pretty new to XSLT/Xquery and would like to compare two xml files ( data content and can ignore white spaces and comments) and print the changed nodes of the second xml. As per my knowledge( googled ) i believe it can be done using Xquery. My xml will look like below.

```
<ns:Batch xmlns:ns="http://www.sample.com/">
<ns:Product>
    <ns:productId>AB02921</ns:productId>
    <ns:type>Product</ns:type>
    <ns:productDescription>
        <ns0:string xmlns:ns0="http://www.sample.com/core" country="US" language="en">EVE BOOTCUT JEAN</ns0:string>
    </ns:productDescription>
    <ns:productLongDescription>
        <ns0:string xmlns:ns0="http://www.sample.com/core" country="US" language="en">For perennial cool with an uber comfortable tw...</ns0:string>
    </ns:productLongDescription>
    <ns:posDetails>
        <ns:isTemplate>false</ns:isTemplate>
    </ns:posDetails>
    <ns:isTemplate>false</ns:isTemplate>
    <ns:lastUpdated>2011-09-07T16:52:50.573</ns:lastUpdated>
    <ns:exportDetails>
        <ns:isTemplate>false</ns:isTemplate>
    </ns:exportDetails>
    <ns:mmGroupId groupTypeId="mmGroup" groupHierarchyId="ABC" variantGroupTypeId="region" variantGroupId="All" variantGroupHierarchyId="All">JSBFO</ns:mmGroupId>
    <ns:inventoryDetails>
        <ns:isTemplate>false</ns:isTemplate>
    </ns:inventoryDetails>
    <ns:productDimensions>
        <ns:isTemplate>false</ns:isTemplate>
    </ns:productDimensions>
    <ns:warrantyDetails>
        <ns:isTemplate>false</ns:isTemplate>
    </ns:warrantyDetails>
    <ns:standardCostPrice>0.0</ns:standardCostPrice>
    <ns:standardMargin>0.0</ns:standardMargin>
    <ns:colourId colourRangeId="Default">6007</ns:colourId>
    <ns:sizeId sizeRangeId="Default">14</ns:sizeId>
    <ns:styleId>AB029</ns:styleId>
</ns:Product>
```

I need to compare against all these repeating nodes of  can return the changed nodes within this  node. Request all to help me with the same.
Regards,
Sri.

Answer (score 4):

**Comparing two XML documents is a challenging task**, partly because people who ask for this as a rule don't have a good definition of the problem and actually don't know exactly what they are asking for.

This said, **try this standard XPath 2.0 function**:

[**`deep-equal()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-deep-equal)

Answer (score 1):

XML Comparison is not trivial. I tend to use XMLUnit http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/ for this kind of problem

Comment: Hi Dimitre, I believe i have a good understanding of my problem and my requirement is comparing two XML files ( data comparison ) which are using the same XML structure.

Comment: @user823737: You put your comment under the wrong answer, so I saw it just now by accident :) You need to read a little bit on this subject and then you'll be aware of the subtleties. Anyway, `deep-equal()` may turn out to be what you want. In case you decide to accept my answer, it is the one that ends with **`deep-equal()`**  :)

Answer (score -1):

serialize to text with no spaces between >< and compare textually! .  If you want a visual representation then use google diff.  Or use deepequal